# Angular 2 - Chaining http requests

Tags: javascript, http, angular, rxjs

I get a RxJS Observable from an httpService which is the actual http from Angular. Now as soon as I get a postive result from that, I want to process the next http Request which I get from `this.retrieve()`. This is more or less concattening requests. Is there a better way of doing it?

```
return this.httpService.query(data) 
        .map(data => {
            if(data.status > 1)
               this.retrieve().subscribe();
            return data;
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Chaining HTTP requests can be done using `flatMap` or `switchMap` operators. Say we want to make three requests where each request depends on the result of previous one:

```
this.service.firstMethod()
    .flatMap(firstMethodResult => this.service.secondMethod(firstMethodResult))
    .flatMap(secondMethodResult => this.service.thirdMethod(secondMethodResult))
    .subscribe(thirdMethodResult => {
          console.log(thirdMethodResult);
     });
```

This way you can chain as much interdependent requests you want.

---

**UPDATE:** 
As of RxJS version 5.5 pipeable operators were introduced and the syntax has slightly changed:

```
import {switchMap, flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.service
  .firstMethod()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(firstMethodResult => this.service.secondMethod(firstMethodResult)),
    switchMap(secondMethodResult => this.service.thirdMethod(secondMethodResult))
  )
  .subscribe(thirdMethodResult => {
      console.log(thirdMethodResult);
    });
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also see `switchMap()` - [switchMap - learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

Comment: How can i combine the return of all the requests and return that as the result?

Comment: Where do you import flatMap from?

Comment: import {switchMap, flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: But what if the requests aren't dependent and we just need to execute them one after the other? Also, flatMap is now deprecated and renamed to mergeMap.

Comment: @SrdjanPazin If you need to execute them one after the other that means they are interdependent?
If you need to execute them in parallel then look for .forkJoin operator