# Serial and parallel HTTP requests with Angular 5 and RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
<button (click)="onSaveItems()">Save</button>

this.selectedItems = [ 
  {'id': 1, name: 'A'},
  {'id': 2, name: 'B'},
  {'id': 3, name: 'C'},
  {'id': 4, name: 'D'},
  {'id': 5, name: 'E'}
]

this.apiService1.deleteAllItems()
this.apiService2.addItem(itemId)
this.apiService3.addItemLog(itemId)
this.apiService4.addFlag()
```

When a user clicks on the Save button, I want to:

1. Call the apiService1 and delete all items
2. If step 1 was successful, I want to call apiService2 to add selected item
3. If step 2 was successful, I want to call apiService3 to add item log for that specific item
4. Repeat steps 2. i 3. for each item from selectedItems
5. If all item logs are added successfully i want to call apiService4

(Please note that I can not change APIs logic)

Is there a way to do this with Angular and RxJS?

Comment: I don't know the implementation of `this.apiService1` but you will want to subscribe to each result in rxjs. So e.g. ..deleteAllItems().subscribe(() => ... next steps...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Chaining http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626536/angular-2-chaining-http-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using angular http client, and therefore RxJs Observables.

If this is the case, then what you need to do is something along these lines

```
function processItem(item) {
  return this.apiService2.addItem(item)
          .switchMap(itemId => this.apiService3.addItemLog(item))
}

function deleteAllAndThenProcess() {
  return this.apiService1.deleteAllItems()
             .switchMap(() => Observable.from(this.selectedItems)
             .mergeMap(item => processItem(item))
}

function doEverything() {
   deleteAllAndThenProcess()
   .last(() => this.apiService4.addFlag())
   .subscribe(
     () => console.log('processing completed'),
     err => console.error(error)
   )
}
```

Details may be wrong (e.g. I have substituted `itemId` with `item` as parameter of `apiService2.addItem` and `apiService3.addItemLog`, but hopefully this gives an idea on how to chain observables to achieve what you want to achieve. Let me add that this is a typical use case where the power of Observable shines.

You may want to look at [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c) to see more details about a use case which seems pretty similar to yours, even if it talks about node and not Angular.